# npm install - how to trigger npm task as a post-install hook?

Tags: scripting, npm, post-install

After `npm install` is run I would like to run

```
npm run jspm install
```

I have package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall" : "npm run jspm install",
    "jspm": "jspm"
},
```

This throws an error since `npm run jspm install` gets passed to `node` rather than `npm`. What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Why not `"postinstall": "jspm install"` ?

Comment: @FelixKling because that would make the assumption that jspm (and the proper version of jspm) is installed globally on the system

Comment: No, it will pick up the local version if it is installed (afaik). I mean, you have `"jspm": "jspm"` there as well. Why should `"jspm": "jspm"` work differently than `"postinstall": "jspm install"` ?

Comment: @FelixKling hmm...good point, everything in npm scripts is pathed to the `node_modules` directory so yeah that should work. Feel free to make that an answer so I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a reason to reference the `jspm` script. You can refer to `jspm` directly in the `postinstall` script:

```
"postinstall" : "jspm install",
```

Comment: for any reason my start process fails because of this line. If I type "jspm installe" as single command on the command line it will work but as postinstall it will fail. Do you have an idea what could cause this behavior?